# Remove Page from being indexed in Google, Yahoo, Bing

Tags: search-engine

I have a page that I do not want indexed on Google, Yahoo, Bing.
Is:

```
    meta name="robots" content="noindex"
```

The sure way of preventing the page from being indexed?